# How to make an OverlayEntery builder removes itself

Tags: flutter, overlay

I am trying to build an Overlay entry with some buttons. I want the buttons inside the that overlay to call `entry.remove()` when pressed on, but of course I can't use an OverlayEntry before assigning it. Is there a work around for this problem?

```
OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: backgroundColor, borderRadius: borderRadius),
            padding: padding,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: left, top: top, right: right, bottom: bottom),
            child: IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.check), onPressed: () {
entry?.remove()}),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
  overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);
```

I tried just using entry?.remove() but didn't work.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Comment: I just did @Md.YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using `Completer` like this:

```
class Attachments {
  final Completer<void> completer = Completer<void>();
  late OverlayEntry entry;

  void showOverlay(BuildContext context, double width, double height) {
    entry = overlay(
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850]!,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Wrap(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                attachemntElement(
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.abc_outlined,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ), () {
                  completer.complete();
                }),
                attachemntElement(
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.abc_outlined,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ), () {
                  completer.complete();
                }),
                attachemntElement(
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.abc_outlined,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ), () {
                  completer.complete();
                }),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Future<void> removeEntry() async {
    await completer.future;
    entry.remove();
  }
}
```

then the button that will show the overlay:

```
onPressed: () async {
  Attachments attachments = Attachments();
  attachments.showOverlay(context, width, height);
  await attachments.removeEntry();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use late, here is a working example of it.

```dart
class F312 extends StatefulWidget {
  const F312({super.key});

  @override
  State<F312> createState() => _F312State();
}

class _F312State extends State<F312> {
  late OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
  late OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () => overlayEntry.remove(),
              child: const Text("Close"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => overlayState.insert(overlayEntry),
            child: const Text("Show"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Local variable 'entry' can't be referenced before it is declared.
Try moving the declaration to before the first use, or renaming the local variable so that it doesn't hide a name from an enclosing scope. With or without late

Comment: Try with `late` keyword, try to run my snippet

Comment: I did, I Itried it with and widthout late, that is what I meant

Comment: is there a way to use a Completer and wait for it to be completed when pressing a button

Comment: A simple future method will be, depends on what are you trying to archive.  you can make it async method `onPressed: () async {await yourOperation(); overlayEntry.remove(),`

Comment: The answer I posted worked for me using Completer